# PowerShell: Is `$matches` guaranteed to carry down the pipeline in sync with the pipeline variable?

Tags: powershell

First, make some example files:

```
2010..2015 | % { "" | Set-Content "example $_.txt" }

#example 2010.txt                                                                          
#example 2011.txt                                                                          
#example 2012.txt                                                                          
#example 2013.txt                                                                          
#example 2014.txt                                                                          
#example 2015.txt
```

What I want to do is match the year with a regex capture group, then reference the match with `$matches[1]` and use it. I can write this to do both in one scriptblock, in one cmdlet, and it works fine:

```
gci *.txt | foreach { 

    if ($_ -match '(\d+)')       # regex match the year
    {                            # on the current loop variable
        $matches[1]              # and use the capture group immediately
    } 

}
#2010
#2011
#.. etc
```

I can also write this to do the match in one scriptblock, and then reference `$matches` in another cmdlet's scriptblock later on:

```
gci *.txt | where { 

    $_ -match '(\d+)'     # regex match here, in the Where scriptblock

} | foreach {             # pipeline!

    $matches[1]           # use $matches which was set in the previous 
                          # scriptblock, in a different cmdlet
}
```

Which has the same output and it appears to work fine. But is it guaranteed to work, or is it undefined and a coincidence?

Could `'example 2012.txt'` get matched, then buffered. `'example 2013.txt'` gets matched, then buffered. `| foreach` gets to work on `'example 2012.txt'` but `$matches` has already been updated with `2013` and they're out of sync?

I can't make them fall out of sync - but I could still be relying on undefined behaviour.

(FWIW, I prefer the first approach for clarity and readability as well).

Comment: Aside from the pipeline effects, even your first script gave me a number of 2016 because the $_ catched my LastWriteTimer so `$_.Name -match '(\d{4})'`would be a better RegEx. But a very good question indeed.

Comment: @LotPings I created the files today and they didn't trigger on LastWriteTime for me. If I run `gci *.txt | %{ $_ -match '.*'; $matches[0] }` to match everything and output it, I get just the path and filename and nothing else, as I'd expect. How did you run it?

Comment: What @LotPings describes happens only with PowerShell _Core_, such as on macOS, and it may be a bug - at the very least, it's an inconsistency: with PowerShell Core on macOS 10.12.1, as of v6.0.0-alpha.13, it seems that when `$_` is forced into a string context in the context of using the `-match` operator in the given command, it expands differently than on Windows PowerShell (on macOS it expands as it would when outputting to the console, as opposed to how it should in string interpolation).

Comment: I have a german locale and my shortdate format is 2016-12-01, since $_ gives a dir like  output `-a----       2016-12-01     23:47              2 example 2012.txt` matches[1] was 2016 here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no synchronization going on, per se. The second example works because of the way the pipeline works. As each single object gets passed along by satisfying the condition in `Where-Object`, the `-Process` block in `ForEach-Object` immediately processes it, so `$Matches` hasn't yet been overwritten from any other `-match` operation.

If you were to do something that causes the pipeline to gather objects before passing them on, like sorting, you would be in trouble:

```
gci *.txt | where { 

    $_ -match '(\d+)'     # regex match here, in the Where scriptblock

} | sort | foreach {             # pipeline!

    $matches[1]           # use $matches which was set in the previous 
                          # scriptblock, in a different cmdlet
}
```

For example, the above should fail, outputting *n* objects, but they will all be the very  last match.

So it's prudent not to rely on that, because it obscures the danger. Someone else (or you a few months later) may not think anything of inserting a `sort` and then be very confused by the result.

As [TheMadTechnician](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3245749/themadtechnician) pointed out in the comments, the placement changes things. Put the sort after the part where you reference `$Matches` (in the `foreach`), or before you filter with `where`, and it will still work as expected.

I think that drives home the point that it should be avoided, as it's fairly unclear. If the code changes in parts of the pipeline you don't control, then the behavior may end up being different, unexpectedly.

---

I like to throw in some verbose output to demonstrate this sometimes:

#### Original

```
gci *.txt | where { 
    "Where-Object: $_" | Write-Verbose -Verbose
    $_ -match '(\d+)'     # regex match here, in the Where scriptblock

} | foreach {             # pipeline!
    "ForEach-Object: $_" | Write-Verbose -Verbose
    $matches[1]           # use $matches which was set in the previous 
                          # scriptblock, in a different cmdlet
}
```

#### Sorted

```
gci *.txt | where { 
    "Where-Object: $_" | Write-Verbose -Verbose
    $_ -match '(\d+)'     # regex match here, in the Where scriptblock

} | sort | foreach {             # pipeline!
    "ForEach-Object: $_" | Write-Verbose -Verbose
    $matches[1]           # use $matches which was set in the previous 
                          # scriptblock, in a different cmdlet
}
```

The difference you'll see is that in the original, as soon as `where` "clears" an object, `foreach` gets it right away. In the sorted, you can see all of the `where`s happening first, before `foreach` gets any of them.

`sort` doesn't have any verbose output so I didn't bother calling it that way, but essentially its `Process {}` block just collects all of objects so it can compare (sort!) them, then spits them out in the `End {}` block.

---

### More examples

First, here's a function that mocks `Sort-Object`'s collection of objects (it doesn't actually sort them or do anything):

```
function mocksort {
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    [Parameter(
        ValueFromPipeline
    )]
    [Object]
    $O
)

    Begin {
        Write-Verbose "Begin (mocksort)"

        $objects = @()
    }

    Process {
        Write-Verbose "Process (mocksort): $O (nothing passed, collecting...)"

        $objects += $O
    }

    End {
        Write-Verbose "End (mocksort): returning objects"

        $objects
    }
}
```

Then, we can use that with the previous example and some sleep at the end:

```
gci *.txt | where { 
    "Where-Object: $_" | Write-Verbose -Verbose
    $_ -match '(\d+)'     # regex match here, in the Where scriptblock

} | mocksort -Verbose | foreach {             # pipeline!
    "ForEach-Object: $_" | Write-Verbose -Verbose
    $matches[1]           # use $matches which was set in the previous 
                          # scriptblock, in a different cmdlet
} | % { sleep -milli 500 ; $_ }
```

Comment: Spectacular answer, I just wanted to add that many times it just comes down to placement. If you move the `Sort` before the `Where` it may be a touch slower, but it no longer breaks the logic. Same if you move it after the `ForEach-Object` scriptblock.

Comment: If you change the `foreach {}` code in the no-sort first example so it prints, sleeps, prints again - e.g. `foreach {   "$_,     $($matches[1])";    start-sleep 1;    "$_,     $($matches[1])" }` then what you get is delayed doubled output, but still all matched up. The `foreach` block is asleep for long enough for `where` to process all the remaining items, but that doesn't happen. The `where` block hasn't run(?), and `$matches` hasn't changed by the time the foreach wakes up. How does `where` know whether you're piping it to a buffering cmdlet, or a non-buffering cmdlet?

Comment: @TheMadTechnician yes absolutely, that's also what makes it dangerous!

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler `where` _doesn't_ know. It has no idea what comes afterwards. In fact, when demonstrating pipelines, in addition to the verbose output I added, I usually throw in a sleep so that you can see it going step by step. Nothing happens asynchronously in the pipeline; one object gets processed, passed along to the next function/cmdlet, and so on, and then the next object is processed. If you added sleeps in an example with sort (before the sort), all the waits will happen before sort is done and the final output will come out all at once.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler bringing it further, that means you can slow down the entire pipeline without having access to the any of the other code, for example, if you do `gci C:\Windows | % { sleep 1 ; $_ }` you'll get a very slow listing; roughly one item per second.

Comment: `where|sort` sends all 5 things to sort, even while sort "is still running". `where|foreach {sleep}` doesn't act like that, proof: `$matches` is unchanged when `foreach` wakes up - `where` has not done anything in that time. I get it now - Process vs End. a) All `begin {}` blocks. b) one thing fed to every `process {}` in pipeline, single thread. c)  finally, `end {}` blocks drain into remaining pipeline as new `process {}` input. Repeat b) c) until done.  So `where|sort` - sort finishes `process{}` and `where` runs again. `where|foreach{sleep}` makes `process {}` blocking and `where` "waits".

Comment: i.e. if the cmdlets only output from their `process {}` blocks, then my match/$matches pair in different places will work by virtue of the pipeline being single threaded, but if they output from `end {}` then match/$matches in different places won't work. Since that distinction depends on knowing the inner workings of every cmdlet, it's Not guaranteed to work, don't use. "*It breaks encapsulation and modularity principles wrt treating the cmdlets as isolated components*". Thanks @briantist.

Answer (score 4):

To complement [briantist's great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40920646/45375):

**Aside from *aggregating* cmdlets such as `Sort-Object`** (cmdlets that (must) collect all input first, before producing any output), **the `-OutBuffer` common parameter can also break the command**:

```
gci *.txt | where -OutBuffer 100 { 

    $_ -match '(\d+)'     # regex match here, in the Where scriptblock

} | foreach {             # pipeline!

    $matches[1]           # use $matches which was set in the previous 
                          # scriptblock, in a different cmdlet
}
```

This causes the `where` (`Where-Object`) cmdlet to buffer its first 100 output objects until the 101th object is generated, and only then send these 101 objects on, so that `$matches[1]` in the `foreach` (`ForEach-Object`) block will in this case only see the *101th* (matching) filename's capture-group value, in *every* of the (first) 101 iterations.

Generally, with an `-OutputBuffer` value of N, the first N + 1 `foreach` invocations would all see the same `$matches` value from the (N + 1)-th input object, and so forth for subsequent batches of N + 1 objects.

From [`Get-Help about_CommonParameters`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameter):

> When you use this parameter, Windows PowerShell does not call the 
>           next cmdlet in the pipeline until the number of objects generated
>           equals OutBuffer + 1. Thereafter, it sends all objects as they are
>           generated.

Note that the last sentence suggests that only the first N + 1 objects are subject to buffering, which, however, is *not* true, as the following example (thanks, @briantist) demonstrates:

```
1..5 | % { Write-Verbose -vb $_; $_ } -OutBuffer 1 | % { "[$_]" }
VERBOSE: 1
VERBOSE: 2
[1]
[2]
VERBOSE: 3
VERBOSE: 4
[3]
[4]
VERBOSE: 5
[5]
```

That is, `-OutBuffer 1` caused *all* objects output by `%` (`ForEach-Object`) to be batched in groups of 2, not just the first 2.

Comment: This is fantastic! I've managed to completely ignore this parameter forever somehow. I love learning new things like this. And I can think of a (small) few situations where I might have actually used it.

Comment: mklement0 Interesting, I didn't know OutputBuffer was a thing.  What's it useful for?  @briantist ... like when might you have used it?

Comment: Here's a quick thing I did to satisfy my curiosity: `1..100 | % { Write-Verbose $_ -Verbose ; $_ } -OutBuffer 50 | select -f 10`. In PSv3, cmdlets got the ability to stop the pipeline, so adding something like `select -first 1` would stop the whole pipeline after the first object. In v2, it would _output_ the first object only, but still process all of the remaining. As expected, using a buffer will prevent these cmdlets from stopping any shorter than the previous buffer size.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler as we've seen with inserting `sleep`s, commands down the pipeline can slow down processing of the whole pipeline. Depending on what you're doing. If early commands are time sensitive, buffering may offer better efficiency and this gives you a way to do it. It gives more control over the process. Also note that one specific function in the pipeline can return multiple objects. These are processed one at a time as well. That _could_ be very bad if later elements interrupt and the op is supposed to be atomic. Knowing you return 3 objs on every call, you can `-OutBuffer 3`.